# check in/out word documents using team foundation server 2013

Tags: ms-word

How can I check in/out word documents using team foundation server 2013?
I was wondering if team foundation server can check in/out my codes, it should be able to check in/out my documentations as well. Anyways, I am using Word 2010.

Comment: This isn't programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

You can store any kind of files in TFS, even big files in the order of Gigabytes.

Then you have to consider if a specific kind of file should be in version control or not, and this is more opinion and related to your organization processes than hard facts.

If it is OK storing Office documents, consider the version control settings (.gitignore, TFVC "File types" for exclusive checkout and merging).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question and more about ALM in general.

Giulio is exactly correct -- using TFS you can check in any kind of files you want.  Images, code, documentation, help files, binary files, certificates, etc etc.  *Anything.*

However, this may not be what you really want to do.  If you are talking about a document, such as a Requirements Document, you really should be storing those requirement items in TFS directly, using their Work Item Tracking (bug, task, requirements, etc) features.  If you do this you can create documents that will stay in sync as you edit them by pulling the information directly from the TFS Work Item store.

You should check out the **TeamSpec** product for managing your TFS requirements inside Word Documents and keeping them in sync:
[www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamspec](http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamspec)

Good Luck!